# How to Save Longitude Latitude Geolocation User Visitor from HTML 5 to Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, html

I have this code I'm working with for the google maps API.
I would like to save the latitude and longitude to the database for retrieval later.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var watchId, geocoder, startLat, startLong;
var start = 1;

window.onload = function(){
    if (navigator.geolocation){watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError,
                                                                             {maximumAge:60*1000, 
                                                                              timeout:5*60*1000, 
                                                                              enableHighAccuracy:true});

    }
}

function onSuccess(position){
    var currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
    var currentLong = position.coords.longitude;

        alert("Latitude: "          + position.coords.latitude          + "\n" +
              "Longitude: "         + position.coords.longitude         + "\n" +
              "Altitude: "          + position.coords.altitude          + "\n" +
              "Accuracy: "          + position.coords.accuracy          + "\n" +
              "Altitude Accuracy: " + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + "\n" +
              "Heading: "           + position.coords.heading           + "\n" +
              "Speed: "             + position.coords.speed             + "\n" +
              "Timestamp: "         + position.timestamp                + "\n");


    if (start == 1){
        startLat = currentLat;
        startLong = currentLong;

        start = 0;
    }

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLat, currentLong);

    geocoder.geocode({'latLng':latlong}, function(results, status){

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){

            if (results){
                document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = "Lokasi Sekarang: " + results[0].formatted_address;

            }
        }
        else
                alert("Tidak Dapat Menampiklan Lokasi Anda");
    });

    var mapOptions = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(startLat, startLong), zoom: 10, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapArea"), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlong, map: map});
}

function onError(error){
    alert("code: "    + error.code    + "\n" +
          "message: " + error.message + "\n");

    switch(error.code){

        case PERMISSION_DENIED:
            alert("User denied permission");
            break;

        case TIMEOUT:
            alert("Geolocation timed out");
            break;

        case POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            alert("Geolocation information is not available");
            break;

        default:
            alert("Unknown error");
            break;
    }
}

</script>
<center><div id="mapArea" style="height:450px; width:490px;"></div></center>
```

I Don't Know how to create the code to save it into MySql database.

What will be the best approach to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi, wat server side programming language are you using.

Comment: First question first do you know how to store data from Js to MySql? If yes then you should know how to store this geographical data in the database.
Please specify your problem- is it you know mysql or you dont? Or you tried to code but it failed?

Comment: Like @Web Dev Guy asks, it depends on the server side language you are using. You need to send the data to be saved to the server from your web page either by submitting a form, or using AJAX.